# How do you change the search parameters for a Virtual (Search) Folder?

Tags: 2013, cme, search

We can update a Virtual (search) Folder's name, description, and metadata in the Content Manager Explorer.

We can also change the search parameters (example below) in the Source tab.

```
<SearchFolder xmlns="http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.1/SearchFolder" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <GeneralParameters>
        <SearchQuery>TV</SearchQuery>
        <SearchIn xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="tcm:0-1-1" Recursive="true"></SearchIn>
    </GeneralParameters>
    <AdvancedParameters>
        <ItemTypes>
            <ItemType>16</ItemType>
        </ItemTypes>
        <Modified>
            <LastDays>1</LastDays>
        </Modified>
        <NumberOfItems>50</NumberOfItems>
    </AdvancedParameters>
</SearchFolder>
```

**How do we change these parameters without updating the XML?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By selecting an existing Virtual Folder and conducting a new Advanced Search, the CME will prompt you with a Modal pop-up to optionally update or save a new Virtual Search folder.

[image: Update virtual folder]

*I didn't realize this was possible and accidentally found this feature while updating training materials.* :-)

Comment: Nice share Alvin.

Comment: I didn't know about that. Does it put the existing values in the Advanced Search fields? Otherwise, it might be more reliable to stick with the XML if you're only tweaking one thing.

Comment: You *could* have checked too, but good question. :-) Yes, when you click on the Virtual Folder it runs the query and then choosing `Show Advanced Search` will show the Virtual Folder's specific search parameters. Saving a new search for a Virtual Folder will even update the source XML (and take you to the Virtual Folder) even if the Virtual Folder is open.